# Get the reference of a cell containing a certain text

Tags: excel, text, reference, cell

I have somewhere in my worksheet a cell containing a specific text (for exemple "hello") and I want to know which cell is it. I want to know the reference of this cell (for exemple "B52").

I tried some things with the INDEX or MATCH formula but I'm quite confused about how should I do for this kind of query.

It would be great if someone could give some tips.

Thank's in advance !

Comment: I think you might get a better answer with more context. If, for example, you then need to refer to cells in the same row as the found cell, Index and Match are the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub WhereIs()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If InStr(1, r.Text, "hello") > 0 Then
        MsgBox r.Address
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

Here is the same approach in User Defined Function *(UDF)* format:

```
Public Function WhereIs(rIn As Range, sIn As String) As String
    WhereIs = ""
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rIn
        If InStr(1, r.Text, sIn) > 0 Then
            WhereIs = r.Address(0, 0)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

and here is an example of its use in the worksheet:

[image: demo]

**EDIT#2**

It is possible to lookup a value in two dimensions without **VBA**
say we have data like:

[image: next]

In **K1** enter:
hello
In **K2** enter the *array formula*

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$H$14=K1,COLUMN($A$1:$H$14)-COLUMN($A$1)+1))
```

In **K3** enter the *array formula*

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$H$14=K1,ROW($A$1:$H$14)-ROW($A$1)+1))
```

In **K4** enter:

```
=ADDRESS(K3,K2)
```

**K2** gives the column, **K3** gives the row, and **K4** gives the address of the cell ($E$11)

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Comment: Thank you for your comment !
This works fine I get the right cell, but is there anyway to get it in another way than popup window? The real purpose of what I want to do is to find the reference of a cell with a specific text that I pass through an argument and then use this reference in other formulas.

EDIT: I'm a beginner with excel's macro.

Comment: It's not at all clear the OP doesn't need a User Defined Function. I think they may be trying to accomplish some basic lookup type activities. If so, this approach could be confusing.

Comment: I came up with a very similar solution to your array formula, but mine and yours have a fatal flaw:  If there were a second "hello" in cell G3, the output would be "E3."  But +1 for the ADDRESS function.  I was using CHAR(64+column) to get the column name.

Comment: how can i use a wild card so that i can identify a cell like "something hello"

Comment: @RamithHettiarachchi  I am also interested in doing that.............please post a new question and mention this **Q/A** as a reference.