# Get the reference of a cell containing a certain text with wildcards

Tags: excel, array-formulas, vba

actually the answer for this question is already here.

[Get the reference of a cell containing a certain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566995/get-the-reference-of-a-cell-containing-a-certain-text)

which can be done without using macros,

But the problem I have is that I want to search for a certain text with a wild card.

`example: DOM???text`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `InStr()` function for the `Like` Operator. Code would look like:

```
Public Function WhereIs(rIn As Range, sIn As String) As String
    WhereIs = ""
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In rIn
        If r.Text Like sIn Then
            WhereIs = r.Address(0, 0)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next r
End Function
```

You have to make sure that your `sIn` string has the correct wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Just run it and search for the word in the dialog box. Then it will give you the cell reference.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub FindText()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FindString As Variant
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

FindString = InputBox("Search for value")

If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then
Set rng = ws.Cells.Find( _
             What:=FindString, _
             LookIn:=xlValues, _
             LookAt:=xlPart, _
             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
             SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
             MatchCase:=False, _
             SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then

MsgBox rng.Address

Else
MsgBox "Nothing found"
End If
End If
End Sub
```